# $(document).ready(function(){ }); doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am working on a project for school right now. I am creating a website which graphically shows measurements taken by a robot.
These measurements are stored in a database, got already processed by a php script and are now transmitted via ajax and json in order to use them in js.

I am by now pretty sure that it's the `$(document).ready(function()` that doesn't fire. which is strange because if i "load" a less demanding php-file(the current one takes 2.5 sec. to be loaded by ajax), everything works perfectly and the code gets executed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost/graph/data.php",
        type : "GET",
        success : function(data){

        // everything in here doesn't get executed

        },
        error : function(data) {

        }
    });
});
```

I really don't know what I am doing wrong - but that i will told pretty soon i hope.
I hope I made myself understood and apologize for wasting your time with my stupid questions and any mistakes I made but English isn't my nativ language.

Comment: You did try a `console.log` and checked the error console, right?

Comment: Can you post more of your html? My question is jquery loaded before this script runs?

Comment: Maybe your error function is executing? Try to debug with console.log statements in both success and error functions

Comment: If you have written code in js file so check have you added that js file entry in your html page? And if you are calling inside html page so check have you kept this code inside <script>  tag?

Comment: Have you added jquery library?

Comment: I do have indeed correctly included the needed JavaScript files. I followed Mehul Mohans advice.  The error function got executed and i did check before asking. I feel pretty stupid by now but thanks for all your advice without your guys help i would still be looking for that error! Thanks!